# TypeError - can't convert Hash into Integer: activerecord (4.2.6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I migrate my application from Rails 3.2.13 to 4.2.6, when I tried to run the application and submit the form, this is the error I am getting:

> TypeError - can't convert Hash into Integer:   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:325:in
>   `sanitize_limit'   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:872:in`build_arel'
>   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:858:in `arel'
>
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation.rb:639:in`
>   exec_queries'   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in`to_a'   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:500:in
>   `find_nth_with_limit'   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:125:in`first'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `first'
>
>   orm_adapter (0.0.7) lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:42:in`
>   get'   devise (1.4.9) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:90:in
>   `serialize_from_session'   devise (1.4.9)
>   lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb:27:in`deserialize'   warden (1.0.6)
>   lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:31:in `fetch'   warden (1.0.6)
>   lib/warden/proxy.rb:182:in`user'   warden (1.0.6)
>   lib/warden/proxy.rb:278:in `_perform_authentication'   warden (1.0.6)
>   lib/warden/proxy.rb:90:in`authenticate'   devise (1.4.9)
>   lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:53:in `current_user'   devise
>   (1.4.9) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:49:in`user_signed_in?'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:102:in `set_user_time_zone'

This is my method in the controller code:

```
def set_user_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if user_signed_in?
end
```

Does I need to modify this method or add any piece of code in my config? Please help.

Comment: Which devise version are you using? Looks like one's pretty old and is not compatible with Rails 4.

Comment: I am using *1.4.9* version.

Comment: Try to upgrade devise to ~> 3.5.2 https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3-stable/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I changed. All my css is vanished.

Comment: Are you sure it is devise upgradation issue because I haven't upgraded while upgrading Rails and some of the gems?

Comment: @venkat Did you eventually find a solution for this issue? Seems I'm facing a similar problem